# Create Multiple Codemirrors and Save The Value To Textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, codemirror

I'm using codemirror in my blog, here is the code:

```
var codeJs = document.getElementsByClassName("code-js");
var editor = [];

for (var i=0; i<codeJS.length; i++){
  editor[i] = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(codeJS[i], {
    lineNumbers: true,
    matchBrackets: true,
    autoCloseBrackets: true
  });
  // Save the value of every codemirror to the textarea
  editor[i].on("blur", function() {editor[i].save()});
}
```

I use the above code for multiple codemirrors and I want to save the value of every codemirrors to their own textarea, it work fine except this line:

```
editor[i].on("blur", function() {editor[i].save()});
```

Can anyone figureout what's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 2):

Try this
editor[i].on("blur", function(codeMirror) {codeMirror.save()});

Comment: To clarify: the actual problem is that the `i` variable is shared by all the functions you're creating, and it will end up with the value `editor.length` at the end of the loop, so if the function is actually called, it won't find an editor at `editor[i]`. The solution described by Bala is a good workaround.